# JQueryMobile list-item goes black upon mouseover

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

On my own site, when hovering over a list-item, it highlights black, instead of the darker gradiented background which appears when hovering on the [JQueryMobile Docs website](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-ul.html).

[image: Black list-item]

I found my code [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) under the "basic linked lists" right at the top. I have tried giving it other themes etc. but nothing seems to solve this simple issue.

Here is my piece of code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
    <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
```

The only thing I can think of is the container in which the list is held, or something, but it's not that...

Here's my setup:
Running Rails 3.2.6 with the latest JQuery and latest JQueryMobile.

What could possibly cause this, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me too. If you delete app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss, lists should no longer have a black background when hovering over them.